# calloc c-style pointer casting to c++ casting style

Tags: c++

I want to convert the following type-casting to c++ style. What's the best way to do this?

```
MemDigest *pMemDigestArray = (MemDigest *)calloc(numUniqueTypes, sizeof(*pMemDigestArray));
```

Comment: Um, converting bad C code into C++? The cast is not needed in C.

Comment: yes, but it's needed in c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<MemDigest> v(numUniqueTypes);
```

"What's C++ about this?", I hear you ask. This:

- Absence of manual memory and lifetime management
- Absence of raw pointers
- Exception safety
- Trivial to resize the container at runtime
- Avoid uninitialized states (by value-initializing your POD-class)

Comment: answered 36 secs ago, 3 upvotes... I'll never get there, damnit.

Comment: I've got "C-style pointer casting" error message produced by cppcheck. So, I'm trying to resolve the issue. Isn't that supposed to be
std::vector<MemDigest*> v(numUniqueTypes); ?

Comment: @Bdar No, it's not supposed to be a container of pointers to `MemDigest`s, but actually a container of `MemDigest`s themselves. No pointer in the template type. You can't use a `vector` exactly like a pointer.

Comment: @Bdar: But almost. `v.data()` gives you a pointer to the contiguous range of elements, just like your `pMemDigestArray`.

Comment: @KerrekSB is there a way to write it as MemDigest *pMemDigestArray = reinterpret_cast<MemDigest *>(malloc(numUniqueTypes*sizeof(*pMemDigestArray))) but without malloc? Changing my code to vector will result in a messier code. Sorry for this kind of questions, I'm not pro on this.

Answer (score 0):

`vector` is a good way to go, but this is a more direct equivalent which is still "c++ style":

```
std::unique_ptr<MemDigest[]> pMemDigestArray(new MemDigest[numUniqueTypes]);
```

Comment: This doesn't have the same effect as `calloc`. You forgot the `()` :-)